# "Tensor like" category with non isomorphism associators

Tags: reference-request, category-theory

I have a situation which I believe is simple enough it has a name that I cannot find:

A category $C$ and a functor $\otimes : C \times C \to C$ and a natural transformation $a: id \times \otimes \Rightarrow \otimes \times id$ and two sided unitors (which are isomorphisms) satisfying the triangle and pentagon coherence conditions.

This is some kind of a weak version of a monidal cateogry.

How such categories are called?

Comment: I know for sure I have seen it in an article, but I can't remember where. I'll try to look for it (this comment isn't as useless as it may seem : it implies that such a name exists)

Comment: It looks like a special case (with invertible unitors) of right-monoidal category in the sense of this article : https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0001870812002575 The introduction mentions other examples of similar notions that could also be of interest.

Comment: @Arnaud D. The references in the paper you linked seem to be exactly what I'm looking for. Thank you!